# Remote Access software with USB Redirect or Biometrics?

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop

Are there any pieces of software that allow USB redirection or work with biometrics? I want to plug in a fingerprint scanner on my computer and use it on a remote pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot depends on the Operating System being run at **both** ends of the connection but for a Windows 7 machine running as your session the default Remote Desktop Connection can forward local devices to the remote machine as explained [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/how-can-i-use-my-devices-and-resources-in-a-remote-desktop-session) but not all remote machines will accept those connections and it may also depend on your privileges on the remote machine. If you are plugging in a device that the remote machine has never seen before and you do not have the rights to install new hardware then it will not work.

To make sure that the instructions do not move I am duplicating them below, *(these are for Win 7 but I suspect other versions of Windows will be similar)*.

## To redirect devices and resources

1. Open Remote Desktop Connection by clicking the **Start** button [image: Start Symbol]. In the search box, type **Remote Desktop
   Connection**, and then, in the list of results, click **Remote Desktop
   Connection**.
2. Click **Options**, and then click the **Local Resources tab**.
3. Under **Local devices and resources**, select the devices or resources
   you want to redirect.
4. To see additional devices, or to redirect Plug and Play devices or
   drives and devices that you plug in later, click **More**.
5. To redirect supported Plug and Play devices, under **Local devices and
   resources**, double-click **Other supported Plug and Play (PnP) devices**.

   The Plug and Play devices that support redirection and are currently
   plugged in appear in this list.
6. To redirect supported USB devices, under **Local devices and
   resources**, double-click **Other supported RemoteFX USB devices**. The
   USB devices that support redirection and are currently plugged in
   appear in this list.
7. Select the check box next to each device that you want to redirect.
8. To automatically redirect drives or devices that you plug in or
   connect to in the future, under Local devices and resources,
   double-click **Drives**, and then click **Drives that I plug in later**.
   ***– or –***
   Double-click **Other supported Plug and Play (PnP) devices**, and then click **Devices that I plug in later**.